# React Redux - storing redux state inside component's state after data is fetched via reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I want to render an editable table that its initial data is being fetched by a reducer.
I added a call to an action that brings the table rows inside `componentDidMount` and when the data is fetched I want to save it inside the component's local state so I could use the map method and render the table body and add an `onChange` event to each input inside the table that will set the new state.

I cannot map the data that is returned from the reducer because I don't want it to be editable until the user presses a "save" button.

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just handle all of the state updates and changes via Redux and then use React's lifecycle methods to handle rendering your state from Redux? You could still map over your data, it would just be coming from your Redux store.

Comment: I could do  so... but I may want to add also a button which cancel the entire changes I made, so it would be easier for me just to keep a replica of the data...